# Increase memory allocation in TOAD

Tags: oracle, toad

How to start TOAD with a bigger memory allocation?

Whenever I try to execute a proc in TOAD that deals with large data sets, it hangs!

Comment: Not really a programming question. I suggest you try the [Toad Yahoo Group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/toad/), which is an excellent source for Toad help (the Toad developers participate in it). Or visit [Quest Support](http://support.quest.com/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the problem is inside TOAD?  If you are running a database procedure that deals with a large amount of data internally, it won't necessarily need to return all that data to TOAD.  Have you monitored the memory usage of TOAD while the procedure is executing?

Can you execute the same procedure using SQLPlus?

Comment: So the TOAD is taking a memory of 100K...but the proc hangs. How to go about debugging it? Will committing more often help?